# Rebuild Facebook Javascript Object by just using the signed_request

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

We are stuck into a scenario where the Facebook app we just finished building has to reside inside of a parent iFrame. (This was an unknown to us until now)
We are wondering if there is an way to easily build the PHP Facebook Object and the JavaScript Facebook Object by only using the 'signed_request' token.
If not, would it make any sense to try and get the parent iFrame to send us the facebook cookies somehow and us setting those same cookies and then trying to build the objects?

Any help on this would be extremely appreciated as we are stuck very few days before launching.

Comment: you mean like facebook connect and using their PHP SDK with it?

Comment: @Computer the SDK object (JS or PHP) has to be inited given a signed_request token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook object is constructed locally. It desn't even need a signed_request. 
I believe it will be enough to pass the signed request as $_GET parameter to internal frame so Facebook class can pick it from there:

```
  public function getSignedRequest() {
    if (!$this->signedRequest) {
      if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
        $this->signedRequest = $this->parseSignedRequest(
          $_REQUEST['signed_request']);
      } else if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->getSignedRequestCookieName()])) {
        $this->signedRequest = $this->parseSignedRequest(
          $_COOKIE[$this->getSignedRequestCookieName()]);
      }
    }
    return $this->signedRequest;
  }
```

setAccessToken is a public function, so it would be no problem to use it as well if you need an access token.

Sadly I'm not good enough to give you an advice for JavaScript :(

Comment: This is good, thanks. Should have taken a look at the lib first prbbly. Gonna take a look at the JS lib (I'll assume they have a nonminified version somewhere) and see what they read into it, and hopefully they do the same thing as in the PHP lib

Comment: I'll set this answer to accepted if no one else answers about the JS version